# ERROR [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC] (10001) General error: invalid vector subscript ALTER Command Failed

Tags: sql, teradata

While trying to add a column in Teradata with the following query

```
ALTER TABLE DB121.CUSTOMER_OPTION ADD (OPTION_CODE VARCHAR(4000) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
```

I get the following error

> "ERROR [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC] (10001) General error: invalid vector subscript ALTER Command Failed."

I am using TTU 17.xx ODBC drivers

I have tried ADD COLUMN and column_name with and without parentheses. Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Strange error. Remove the () around the new column

Comment: Nevermind, there was a connectivity error in the backend. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, there was a connectivity issue in the backend. Sorry for the trouble. I closed the application (Nexus) and came back after half an hour or so and tried again and it was working. Not sure if it was application issue or VPN or my network.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD column_name datatype
```

In your case:

```
ALTER TABLE DB121.CUSTOMER_OPTION ADD COLUMN OPTION_CODE VARCHAR(4000) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC
```

While I do not have the means to test this currently, this should work. Your error message is likely complaining about some other problem in your script.